# Presentation layer and domain model classes naming conventions

Tags: naming-conventions, data-access-layer, presentation

What are the naming conventions you use for application domain model classes and presentation layer classes? Postfixes/Prefixes to distinguish the aim of the class from the first sight:

For example information about the person that is returned from DAL can be

```
public class PersonEntity 
{
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public SexType Sex { get; set; }
  public Date Birthdate { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public string Family { get; set; }
  public string Patronymic { get; set; }
  ...
}
```

or may be you prefer `PersonData` or `PersonInfo` or something more appropriate?

Than I use databinding to create appropriate presentation. For example `SexType` should be converted to localized string (Male, Mann, Homme, Hombre, ...) `Birthdate` to appropriate date format (YYYY.MM.DD, DD.MM.YYYY, ...) and full name into -> Family N.P.

So I use another layer of classes for presentation databindings. Something like

```
public class PersonDecorator
{
  public string Sex { get; set; }
  public string Date { get; set; }
  public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

or may it's better to name such class `PersonPresenter`, or `PersonView`, or something more appropriate?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The `EntityPurpose` convention for class names works just fine in a lot of places, especially if you have several entities (Persons, Cars, etc) and several layers (Model, View, Action, etc).

I'd name your class `PersonPresentation`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Pavel. Waiting what others will say